# S3 object still in bucket after successfully deleting it and the delete marker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cdk

I've built this context manager to create a temporary object in S3 for testing purposes:

```
from types import TracebackType
from typing import BinaryIO, Optional, Type

import boto3


class S3Object:
    def __init__(self, file_object: BinaryIO, bucket_name: str, key: str):
        self.file_object = file_object
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name
        self.key = key
        self.s3 = boto3.client("s3")

    def __enter__(self) -> "S3Object":
        self.s3.upload_fileobj(self.file_object, self.bucket_name, self.key)
        return self

    def __exit__(
        self,
        exc_type: Optional[Type[BaseException]],
        exc_val: Optional[BaseException],
        exc_tb: Optional[TracebackType],
    ) -> bool:
        delete_object_response = self.s3.delete_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=self.key)
        # Delete version marker
        self.s3.delete_object(
            Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=self.key, VersionId=delete_object_response["VersionId"]
        )
        print("Deleted object")  # debugging
        return False  # Propagate exception
```

I'm using it like this in a single test:

```
with S3Object(BytesIO(), bucket_name, filename) as s3_object:
    …
```

The weird thing is that even though the test output includes the "Deleted object" debug output, the original item is still in the bucket. From the `cdk destroy` output:

> The bucket you tried to delete is not empty. You must delete all versions in the bucket.

It is definitely the right file, because I generate a unique filename based on the test name. It also doesn't seem to be a timing issue, because this is 100% reproducible.

I can delete the file manually, so there doesn't seem to be any special protection in place either.

After modifying the code to print both responses, I'm wondering if I was just deleting the delete marker twice? Abbreviated for readability:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 204, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-version-id': 'd08uv05t7lU7YKle4kMSURa_jrMU.GSL', 'x-amz-delete-marker': 'true'}}, 'DeleteMarker': True, 'VersionId': 'd08uv05t7lU7YKle4kMSURa_jrMU.GSL'}
{'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 204, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-version-id': 'd08uv05t7lU7YKle4kMSURa_jrMU.GSL', 'x-amz-delete-marker': 'true'}}, 'DeleteMarker': True, 'VersionId': 'd08uv05t7lU7YKle4kMSURa_jrMU.GSL'}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading this but to permanently delete a versioned object, you delete the object version ID. You seem to be deleting the object (without version) which inserts a delete marker and returns its version ID to you, and then you delete the delete marker, which effectively brings the object back to life.

Comment: I think @jarmod is correct.  You should use the ListObjectVersions if you want to permanently delete the object and only make one API call and provide the version id: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectVersions.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54081535/96588) I ended up with this:

```
from types import TracebackType
from typing import BinaryIO, Optional, Type

import boto3

DELETE_OBJECTS_MAX_KEYS = 1000


class S3Object:
    def __init__(self, file_object: BinaryIO, bucket_name: str, key: str):
        self.file_object = file_object
        self.bucket_name = bucket_name
        self.key = key
        self.s3 = boto3.client("s3")

    def __enter__(self) -> "S3Object":
        self.s3.upload_fileobj(self.file_object, self.bucket_name, self.key)
        return self

    def __exit__(
        self,
        exc_type: Optional[Type[BaseException]],
        exc_val: Optional[BaseException],
        exc_tb: Optional[TracebackType],
    ) -> bool:
        version_list = []
        object_versions_paginator = self.s3.get_paginator("list_object_versions")
        for object_versions_page in object_versions_paginator.paginate(Bucket=self.bucket_name):
            for marker in object_versions_page.get("DeleteMarkers", []):
                if marker["Key"] == self.key:
                    version_list.append({"Key": self.key, "VersionId": marker["VersionId"]})
            for version in object_versions_page.get("Versions", []):
                if version["Key"] == self.key:
                    version_list.append({"Key": self.key, "VersionId": version["VersionId"]})

        for index in range(0, len(version_list), DELETE_OBJECTS_MAX_KEYS):
            response = self.s3.delete_objects(
                Bucket=self.bucket_name,
                Delete={
                    "Objects": version_list[index : index + DELETE_OBJECTS_MAX_KEYS],
                },
            )
            print(response)

        return False  # Propagate exception
```